# Displaying menu with basic mouseover event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to display the list of menu items when the mouse is over the main item and at the same time hide the previous shown items. But the effect isn't becoming effective. I guess the jquery's code below is not correct to do what I'd like it to. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).read(function(){
         $("MainMNItem:not(:first)").hide();
         $("MainMNItem a").mouseover(function()
         {
             $("Item:visible").slideUp("slow");
             $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
         });
      });
  </script> 
  <style>
     body{font-family:"Times New Roman"; font-size:16px;}
     Menu{width:330px;}
     Item a{color:#000;}
     Item{margin:0;}
     MainMNItem{background:#f11;font-size:18px;padding:5px;width:330px;} 
     MainMNItem a{color:#fff;}
     ul{list-style:none;padding:5px;}
  </style>  
</head>
<body>
   <Menu>
       <MainMNItem><a href="#">Home</a></MainMNItem> 
       <Item>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
           </ul>
       </Item>
       <MainMNItem><a href="#">About Us</a></MainMNItem>
       <Item>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
       </Item>
   </Menu>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it should be 
`$(document).ready(function(){
          ...
       });`

not `read()`. And give a little better and exact explanation if you want any help !!

Comment: Thanks, I helped myself, it works now. Thanks for your pointer